# Scroll to next class

Tags: jquery

How do I make this scroll to the next class?

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a.scroll-to-next-nav').click(function(){
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).closest('.header-icons').nextAll('.header-icons') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

<div class="header-icons"><a href="#" class="scroll-to-next-nav" title="Go to next section">Go to next section</a></div>


<div class="header-icons"><a href="#" class="scroll-to-next-nav" title="Go to next section">Go to next section</a></div>
<div class="header-icons"><a href="#" class="scroll-to-next-nav" title="Go to next section">Go to next section</a></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to prefix your class selectors with dots

Comment: You are right. However, after fixing it still does not seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
scrollTop: $(this).closest('.header-icons').next('.header-icons').offset().top
```

You want to go to the next div (`next()`), not `nextAll()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HZm7a/1/ - that's with your code. Changing it to Jozeidon's code also works, which suggests something wrong on your side. Is your jquery properly included and your code wrapped in $(document).ready() function ?

Comment: I think my class element is not clearing. I changed it to look for next H3 and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps! :)

```
var $root = $('html, body');
var i=$('a.next').length, v=1;
$('a.next').click(function(){
    var to = v<i ? $(this).closest('.page').next('.page').offset().top : 0;
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: to
    }, 500);
    if(v<i) {v++;} else {v=1;}
    return false;
});
```